# Why does the Render View in "3D View" look totally Different than the Rendered image?

Tags: modeling

In "filigree"? handwork I managed to make the textures of my eyes look like this:

[image]

When I render it looks like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: The texture, anyway, doesn#t follow the camera in 3D View anymore, but the rendered image does, maybe? :O

Comment: the problem is in the texture mapping , you need to unwrap the eyes and place the texture corectly than set mapping coordinates to UV and select the UVmap

Comment: Ok, sounds complicated ^^ Maybe im in something like a learning blockade right now because i switched from Gothic2 SPACER to Oblivion SDK to UE3 to UE4 to NeoAxis 3D Engine and never did any Modelling or mapping before Monday :D I really hate that word "UV Mapping" since a few days but i think it'll come with the time ^^ -.-

Comment: someone may give a detailed answer , for me it's bedtime